# MS Access : Combo Box Column order issue

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Combo box on a form and want to populate from table with vba code.  The query has two columns proc_name and then ID and have set combo box column count as 2, but when form is loaded I see ID first and then proc_name. Why is this happening?

For the other combo box with similar table structure they show column order how I have defined in the query.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

   Dim strSQL As String

   createCon

    strSQL = "Select proc_name, ID from tblProcess"

    Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    objRecordset.Open strSQL, objConnection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    If Not (objRecordset.EOF And objRecordset.BOF) Then
        Set Me.cmbProcess.Recordset = objRecordset
    End If

    objRecordset.Close
    Set objRecordset = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What happens with this change? `strSQL = "Select proc_name AS f1, ID AS f2 from tblProcess"`

Comment: When I used your query, it shows correctly, what's the reason?

Comment: It seems the recordset columns are processed in alphabetical order when loading into the combo box.  I aliased the field names so they are processed in the order I think you want.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a ton for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `Recordset` columns are loaded into the combo box, it appears they are processed in alphabetical order (`ID` before `proc_name`).

Alias the fields in your `SELECT` field list so they are processed in the order you wish:

```vb
strSQL = "Select proc_name AS f1, ID AS f2 from tblProcess"
```

Comment: Could you help me with this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655385/unbound-combo-box-selected-text-not-showing