# Unbound Combo box: Selected text not showing

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a unbound combo box which I am populating on form load. What I want is when user selects the combo box text, I should be able to access its value. In this case, selected item text disappears when selected but I can access its value. Below are the combo box setting. What should I do to make combo box show the selected text and at the same time I should be able to access the selected value?

```
ID Process
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

- Column Count - 2
- Column Widths - 0",1"
- Row Source Type - Table/Query

  ```
  Private Sub Form_Load()

  Dim strSQL As String
  strSQL = "Select ID as F1 ,  process_name as F2 from tblProcess"

  Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
  objRecordset.Open strSQL, objConnection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

  If Not (objRecordset.EOF And objRecordset.BOF) Then
      Set Me.cmbProcess.Recordset = objRecordset
  End If

  objRecordset.Close
  Set objRecordset = Nothing
  End Sub
  ```

**The combo box appears after selection**

[image]

**Combo box properties**

[image]

Comment: Change the combo box's color properties: Back Color and/or Fore Color.

Comment: I have tried changing color but its the same. When I try to access the value and text of the combo box after selecting....the '(Form_frmAudit.cmbProcess.Text)' text returns empty string whereas the value '(Form_frmAudit.cmbProcess.value)' returns correct value.

Comment: Are you talking about what the user sees or what is returned by the combo's `.Text` property?

Comment: Both what user sees and .text property are empty string.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `Recordset = objRecordset`?  If you temporarily change the combo Row Source to use a local query, does the selected value then display properly?

Comment: Yes, it works fine then.

Comment: Instead of assigning an `ADO Recordset` as the combo's `Recordset`, create a pass-through query to fetch the same data and use that query as the combo Row Source.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work properly if you skip the whole objRecordset block of code and instead just insert the line after strSQL is defined:

```
Me.cmbProcess.RecordSource = strSQL
```